# Shell and MySql

Tags: mysql, shell, unix

I want to generate the excel file using the shell script for below SQL query

```
SELECT min(UM.USER_ID) USER_ID, min(UM.USER_NAME) USER_NAME, min(UM.USER_EMAIL) USER_EMAIL, min(UM.USER_STATUS) USER_STATUS 
FROM CDR_ETHICON.USER_ROLE_MAP URM INNER JOIN USER_MASTER UM ON URM.USER_ID = UM.USER_ID 
GROUP BY UM.USER_ID HAVING COUNT(UM.USER_ID) > 1
```

For more info, I have a unix server in which oracle SQL developer version 1.5.1.54.40 is installed

Now from that UNIX server I want to fire this SQL query and want an output in excel format so I can automate it and send via mail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a shell script that does the following:

1. Invoke MySQL to execute your query (using [SELECT...INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) to generate the output in CSV format) and redirect the output to a textfile (say, `output.csv`)
2. Invoke your mail program to send the `output.csv` file

Use `cron` to run the whole thing at your desired interval.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in a shell script and run:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -Ddatabase <<EOF
SELECT min(UM.USER_ID) USER_ID, min(UM.USER_NAME) USER_NAME, min(UM.USER_EMAIL) USER_EMAIL, min(UM.USER_STATUS) USER_STATUS 
FROM CDR_ETHICON.USER_ROLE_MAP URM INNER JOIN USER_MASTER UM ON URM.USER_ID = UM.USER_ID 
GROUP BY UM.USER_ID HAVING COUNT(UM.USER_ID) > 1
into outfile 'youfilename.csv'
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n';
EOF
```